Jak zabespieczyc Bluetooth na Androidzie przed atkiem hakera?
Na moje urządzenie Infinix wprowadził się intruz.
Użył do tego Hot spotu i Bluetooth Czy są ustawienia, lub aplikacje które blokują te funkcje w 100% ? Jak załatać lukę w zabezpieczeniu Androida z wersją Bluetooth 4,2 ?
